# faceConfig settings in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, affdex-sdk

I am testing with the free version of the Affectiva package. The input to Affectiva is provided by Kinect. However, Affectiva fails to detect a face after the user is ~1.5 meters away from the camera. However, kinect on it's own can detect and track faces from very high distances.

What I feel is that at the current state, Affectiva only tracks large faces. Is there a way for me to detect and track small faces (i.e. faces at a distance?) From what we had read in the .NET documentation, with the CameraDetector we can specify whether the facetype is large or small. Is there a way I can do that within Unity by changing any of the scripts?

Comment: Also, is there a way to access the CameraDetector from the unity package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~1.5 meters about right for face detection fall off ATM. Kinect can detect at higher ranges because detecting a face does not need as much detail as detecting emotions on that face. Affectiva's face detector is designed to detect faces that the SDK can measure emotions on, so the range is limited.
Toggling large vs small faces isn't exposed in Unity yet, nor is the CameraDetector.